# What is the best order of learning mathematics before start Monte Carlo Methods for Physics simulation?

Tags: soft-question, education, computational-physics, statistics, medical-physics

I doing medical physics masters and hope to start my research in  Monte Carlo methods to simulate some particle interaction and hence to calculate some unknown physical quantities ( Stopping power and mean excitation potential).

I need to learn Monte Carlo from the scratch, because i have very little knowledge of mathematics of Monte Carlo. I went through various books and their mathematics is too advanced to start with. My maths knowledge is limited to university first year.

Comment: "Monte Carlo" is just fancy speak for "random sampling." The math behind it is nothing more than centuries-old probability & statistics. If you've had this, you'll need to be more specific about the issues. If you haven't, you should stop everything you're doing and take a course on it, since no remotely scientific endeavor today can be understood without statistics, least of all medicine. In any event, though, this is probably more appropriate for [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com/) or better yet [Stats](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).